# C#/Razor replace second question mark with ampersand in query string

Tags: javascript, c#, query-string

I am using C# and I have a CMS that uses an open text field.  I am doing a redirect manually appending a query string BUT on top of that, I have editors putting UTMs into the URL.  I am trying to track the redirects/vanity URLs so we an see the success of them, but the editors are adding UTMs and when I am transferring the redirect, I prepend "?ref=" to their URL to the second URL.
I need to know how to replace any subsequent question marks in the query string.
The CMS is seeing the second question mark and automatically redirecting to the homepage, because I think it is trying to be smart with the URL and the second question mark is causing it to think the URL is invalid.

So the original URL I am getting looks something like this:

[www.mysite.com/somepage?utm_source=foo](http://www.mysite.com/somepage?utm_source=foo)&utm_medium=bar

BUT it then redirects so I can track the URL and it looks now like this

[www.myothersite.com/this-other-page?ref=www.mysite.com/somepage?utm_source=foo](http://www.myothersite.com/this-other-page?ref=www.mysite.com/somepage?utm_source=foo)&utm_medium=bar

So what I want to do is in the second URL is to replace the second question mark with an ampersand.  How would I do only the second or subsequent ones without getting rid of the first one?

I am using Javascript to do the redirect in the view.

My code so far

```
@{
var currentPageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
<script type="text/javascript">
  
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = '@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("externalRedirectURL")?ref=@currentPageUrl'; 
}, 200); //will call the function after 2 secs

 </script>
```

Comment: Instead of building them manually, use the [built-in types that already handle this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers?view=aspnetcore-3.1). And if you're not using .NET Core, [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) can also handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer now using HTML.Raw and Json.Ecode.
When I did  generic .Replace in the actual Javascript built string, for some reason the .Replace("?", "&") was adding another ampersand to anything in the query string with an ampersand already in the query string.  Not what I expected.
Anyways, here is my answer

```
 <script>
   var currentP = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@currentPageUrl.Replace("?","&amp;")));
  
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = '@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("externalRedirectURL")' + '?ref=' + currentP; 
   
}, 200); //will call the function after 2 secs
 </script>
```